# Why can't we image an insulating meterial with an SEM?

Tags: electrons, charge, microscopy

I know that insulating materials are difficult to measure for insulating materials because there are charging. The effect is a drift or a moving micrograph.

1. Why does charging cause a drift in the image?
2. Is there some charge compensation at some point?
3. Is there a way to remedy to charging in insulating materials other than coating the insulator with a conducting substrate?

Comment: Charging means there are no potentials (voltages) that were not there when you focused the beam. So, the electrons are experiencing additional forces which are unlikely to help make the image clearer. I learned never to sign up for TEM time after people from the group doing magnetic materials - talk about horrible focusing problems!

Answer (score 1):

The principle idea of a scanning electron microscope (SEM) is to use electrodes to raster the probe with a **tiny** focus: The electrodes shape the electric field lines (electric potentials) in such a way that the electrons propagating in $z$-direction are focussed onto a "small" spot in the $(x,y)$-plane. The "small" focus in the $(x,y)$-plane is responsible for the "high" resolution of the image.

The problem with electrical insulators is that the charges are not free to move. Therefore, the electrons, which are focussed by the SEM onto the material, get "trapped" on the surface of the probe.
The "trapped electrons" change the shape the electric field lines, see Coulomb's law. As a result the focus of the SEM expanse (blurs), and the resolution becomes insufficient. Methods to prevent this charging effect are e.g. coating the insulator with a "thin" coating, which is electrically conducting, and increasing the pressure inside the SEM (using a "bad" vacuum).